# How to know when a Share menu item, backed by a ShareActionProvider, is clicked?

Tags: android, shareactionprovider, android-sharing

The question is simple however I'm struggling to find a working solution. I need my application to know when the click on Share action button happened. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a ShareTargetSelectedListener on the ShareActionProvider to get the *Intent* selected.

```
actionShare.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(new ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider actionProvider, Intent intent) {
                String package = intent.getPackage(); //for example, obtain the package name
            }
        });
```

Hope it helped, Mattia

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this callback will be fired once a sharing method is selected. I need to catch the Share menu item click event.